# setTimeout inside iteration of iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I have the code below and i would like to put a `setTimeout` between each iteration of `Myurl`. There are a number of `classes` and each of them contains a number of elements.

```
//Some calculations before...
var i = 0;
async.whilst(
function () {
    return i <= thefooz.length - 1;
},
function (innerCallback) {

    //Some calculations where I get classes array.

    async.forEachOfSeries(classes, function (Myurl, m, eachDone) {
        // Here I want a delay
        async.waterfall([
            function (next) {
                connection.query(
                    'SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE UrlLink=? LIMIT 1', [Myurl],
                    next
                );
            },
            function (results, fields, next) {
                if (results.length !== 0) {
                    console.log("Already Present");
                    return next();
                }
                console.log("New Thing!");
                request(options2, function (err, resp, body) {
                    if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
                        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                        //Some calculations, where I get AllLinks.
                        var post = {
                            ThisUrl: AllLinks[0],
                            Time: AllLinks[1],
                        };
                        var query = connection.query('Insert INTO mydata Set ?', post, next);
                    };
                });
            }
        ], eachDone);

    }, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        i++;
        innerCallback();
        console.log("Done");
    }, 20000);

    //Some calculations after...
```

So how could I set a delay between each `Myurl` in `async.waterfall`? Say I want a 5 seconds delay. I managed to set `setTimeout` between 
each `async.whilst`iteration but not between each `async.forEachOfSeries` iteration. It simply does not wait, instead it continues to loop until each `async.forEachOfSeries` is done and then calls the `async.whilst` `setTimeout`.

`EDIT`:
Queue solution does not work. That solution seems to just go to next page, and next page and so on, without outputting to my database. Of course I could apply it in the wrong way, but I really tried to do exactly as the example said.

Comment: Please explain what's you problem, why you can't set it inside `async.forEachOfSeries`?

Comment: @SharpEdge It simply does not wait, instead it continues to loop until each `async.forEachOfSeries` is done and then calls the `async.whilst` `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't fully understand how [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) works:

```
(function () {
    var seconds=0;
[1,2,3].forEach(function(value) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Showing value '+value+ 'at '+Date());
    },1000*seconds++);
})
})()
```

This code, for each element, creates a callback function to be executed after a second. Please note that JS is single threaded, so what the code really does is adding "executions" to a queue. So if the current execution does not stop, the callbacks are not called. So the time (in millis) that you pass to the `setTimeout` function as second parameter is just the minimum time to have that code executed.

Then, the execution of those callbacks is made in FIFO order.

**UPDATE**: Here is an example of what I'm explaining:

```
function myFunction() { 
    var test=0;
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("This is the current value of test: "+test); 
    }, 0);
    console.log("This is run first");
    for (var i=0;i<50;i++) {
        test++;
    }
    console.log("Main thread ending, not the callbacks will be executed");
}
```

The setTimeout will wait 0 (zero) before executing, but as the main thread has not finished, it cannot be executed. Then, when the loop ends, the callback is executed, finding that test is 50, not 0.

Comment: could you please post a solution to my question? :)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you really want to do... that code is a bit messy, sorry. For example, why are you passing  `innerCallback`as a parameter if you are not using it within that function? it seems a function itself, that is called in another method :S

Comment: @`innerCallback` is called inside `async.whilst`. Delays each iteration.

Comment: I'm giving you +1 for the easiness of this solution.

Comment: @Pablo So how do you mean I could use your solution? Sharpedges solution does not work:/ Would really appreciate if you can give me some advice:)

Answer (score 7):

First we must implement a simple queue

### Queue

```
function Queue() {
  var obj = {};  
  var queue = [];
  var _delay;
  
  function next() {
    // If queue is empty stops execution
    if(queue.length == 0) return;
    
    // Prepare next call to next
    setTimeout(next, _delay);
    // Take out an element from the queue and execute it.
    (queue.shift())();          
  }
  
  // Add a new function to the queue
  obj.add = function (myFunc) {
    queue.push(myFunc);
  };
  
  // Start the queue execution passing the delay between each call
  obj.run = function(delay) {
    _delay = delay;
    
    // call next function
    next();
  }
  
  return obj;
  
}
```

Then we use it inside the code

```
// create the queue
var myQueue = Queue();

async.forEachOfSeries(classes, function (Myurl, m, eachDone) {
  // Add the function to the queue
  myQueue.add(executeWaterfall.bind(this));
}, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});

// Start the queue with 5 second delay
myQueue.run(5000);

function executeWaterfall() {
  async.waterfall([
    function (next) {
      connection.query(
        'SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE UrlLink=? LIMIT 1', [Myurl],
        next
      );
    },
    function (results, fields, next) {
      if (results.length !== 0) {
        console.log("Already Present");
        return next();
      }
      console.log("New Thing!");
      request(options2, function (err, resp, body) {
        if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
          var $ = cheerio.load(body);
          //Some calculations, where I get AllLinks.
          var post = {
            ThisUrl: AllLinks[0],
            Time: AllLinks[1],
          };
          var query = connection.query('Insert INTO mydata Set ?', post, next);
        };
      });
    }
  ], eachDone);
}
```

This is far from optimal because anyway you are falling in what is called the **Pyramid of doom**

### Bonus

#### Pyramid of doom

When handling asynchronous operations in succession with normal callbacks, you'll end up nesting calls within each other; with this nesting comes more indentation, creating a pyramid (pointing to the right), hence the name "Pyramid of Doom".

#### Solution

In this case is better to use some promise pattern to save your code from the pyramid of doom and facilitate the solution of this kind of issues.

- [More Info](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/what-is-the-point-of-promises)
- [PromiseJS](https://www.promisejs.org/)

Comment: Just one thing: the loop will be executed without waiting, just queuing the callbacks to happen all of them after 5 seconds... you shoud add 5 seconds more to each call to seTimeout

Comment: @Pablo Hm, could you please edit the code, easier to understand then :)

Comment: We should use a queue then

Comment: @user1665355 look at my answer, I'm adding one second to each setTimeout call

Comment: @Pablo where do you add one second? I only see `setTimeout(executeWaterfall.bind(this), 5000);`

Comment: no please don't do this things, i've edited the answer and added a simple queue to handle the execution with delay

Comment: @SharpEdge what do you propose?:)

Comment: You don't need a queue, you can just increment the time to wait in each iteration

Comment: That's a really bad coding style...setTimeout doesn't guarantee that your code will be executed exactly after 5 seconds. if the callback execution takes 10 seconds your next callback will be called after 15 seconds

Comment: @SharpEdge In this case it is not a problem. So your solution will work with my database calls?

Comment: @SharpEdge but it is hard to understand `Queue` function:)

Comment: @SharpEdge, unless you use webworkers JS is single-threaded, so if a callback execution needs n seconds, no matter how you implements the delays, the next execution will wait. Said this, if a callback function launches a new async callback, then the execution will be  executed intertwined

Comment: Now there are comments.
@Pablo You are right however i don't like to throw code, specially when there are delays and timings involved

Comment: So guys, that is the best solution then?

Comment: @SharpEdge Now I see what you are doing... but the execution of the third element will depend on the exection time of the first one, as the setTimeout call is done only when it finishes. If that is not a problem I think this is a valid solution :)

Comment: You should use @Pablo's answer if you need an easy and fast solution, my solution instead if you want something more structured.

Comment: @SharpEdge Well, Pablo did not present a solution, but you did :)

Comment: @SharpEdge I get an error `myfunc` is not defined. It might be a typo and you mean `myFunc`? However your code does not work...It skips everything on each page and does not output to my database:(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not intimately familiar with the `async` library, but to me it looks like `async.waterfall` will call `eachdone` after each run, so that `async.forEachOfSeries` knows that it should execute the next iteration. Assuming that `eachdone` is called without parameters, I would expect the following to work:

```
function executeWaterfall() {
  async.waterfall([
      ......
  ], function () { window.setTimeout(eachDone, 5000));
}
```

If `eachdone` does get parameters, you'd have to send them over as well.

As an alternative I expect you could add another step to your waterfall, one that waits 5 seconds. This will work regardless of parameters for `eachdone` (but may fail if the third waterfall function expects more paraneters):

```
function executeWaterfall() {
  async.waterfall([
    function (next) {
      connection.query(
        'SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE UrlLink=? LIMIT 1', [Myurl],
        next
      );
    },
    function (results, fields, next) {
      if (results.length !== 0) {
        console.log("Already Present");
        return next();
      }
      console.log("New Thing!");
      request(options2, function (err, resp, body) {
        if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
          var $ = cheerio.load(body);
          //Some calculations, where I get AllLinks.
          var post = {
            ThisUrl: AllLinks[0],
            Time: AllLinks[1],
          };
          var query = connection.query('Insert INTO mydata Set ?', post, next);
        };
      });
    },
    function (next) {
      window.setTimeout(next, 5000);
    }
  ], eachDone);
}
```

Now, again I'd like to stress that I'm not familiar with `async` and all examples are untested. Perhaps everything is majorly wrong, but this is my gut feeling.

Answer (score -3):

setTimeout will only delay the result to be shown in the output...it will not delay the execution of methods inside or outside the setTimeout method...In the background the thread will keep running the code after the setTimeout function...Since you are using async you nend to use COMPLETE method of ajax  that will get invoked when you have completed received all the data from the server

Comment: @user1665355 1st let me ask you that did you understand my explanation about setTimeout function ?

Comment: Well `setTimeout` seems to work inside `async.whilst`, it delays execution then!

Comment: No man..setTimeout doesnt delay the execution..it just delays the result to be shown at the output...you can probably test byt writing small amout of code...thats the other part...now your main problem..what i understand is that you want to receive all the response data from the server before you send another request to the server...right ?

Comment: @Shanky setTimeout does delay the execution.

Comment: @Shanky Ok! Yes, I want to receive the data from server before response.

Comment: <script>
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
 alert("This is run first");
}
</script>

For all those who says settimeout function delays execution...please run this code and understand youself..

Comment: @Pablo So you say setTimeout delays execution but Shanky means it does not? I thought it would delay execution because `i++` waits...

Comment: @Shanky I mean, inside `async.whilst` it does delay?

Comment: @shanky you don't understand that snippet you posted: read my answer. I will update it with a new example

Comment: @Pablo can you please explain me how setTimeout function delays execution of code ??

Comment: @Pablo i have read...i am sorry i may be wrong..but technology cannot be wrong..i think you should try it practically and see how setTimeout works...ok i will give you code 
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("setTimeout 1"); }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function(){ alert("This is two"); }, 1000);
}

run it and see the output that setTimeout function1 doesnt delays the execution of setTimeout2 until setTimeout1 completes it process..

Comment: @Shanky setTimeout function just adds the callback to the queue, it does not execute anything. Your code adds two callbacks to be executed and finishes. One second later the second callback is executed. Three seconds later the first one is executed. I don't see your point.

Comment: setTimeout just add the callback to the queue and the 'timeout' does not indicate when the callback will be fired but its the priority that it have in the queue. Look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/sLLaxjhb/ both setTimeout callback are executed after 1020ms but in the priority that the 'timeout' value was set